# Rooted Android - create and read files in root owned directories

Tags: android, io, root

I have seen this questioned asked a couple times but it's never been fully answered (that I can find).

To be clear, my phone is rooted.

What I need to do is read and write files under root owned directories, such-as, `/data`. I understand I need to run it has a superuser (`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");`). But I can't figure out how to do the IO its self.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but it looks like you have all the essential access required. You can provide the file your file is in and read or write using java IO apis.

Comment: I don't believe it's quite that easy. I need to somehow pass the superuser permissions to the IO calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the file to the SD card using something like `su -c cp /data/file.txt /mnt/sdcard`, read it and delete it when done.

Comment: I am looking for alternatives to this Answer because for my app it makes no sense to create a copy of the file I want to read. Because that file is actually a device "/dev/...". I want to read it as a Java stream. The device is rooted.

Comment: Use chmod to change permissions or modify udev, etc. scripts to change permission permanently. If you don't want other apps to be able to read it, it becomes a little bit trickier.

Comment: Yes that is one option. But isn't there a way, with java, to have a stream with "root privileges" obtained from this process Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su") and then pipe other streams (for example a stream for the file i want within /dev/), through that stream?

Comment: No, you cannot elevate privileges in the same process.